# shell scripting error logging

Tags: shell, logging, scripting, descriptor

I'm trying to setup a simple logging framework in my shell scripts. For this I'd like to define a "log" function callable as

```
log "LEVEL" $message
```

Where the message is a variable to which I have previously redirected the outputs of executed commands. My trouble is that I get errors with the following

```
{message=command 2>&3 1>&3 3>&-} >&3
log "INFO" $message
```

There's something wrong isn't there?

TIA

Comment: Errors? What errors? I see no errors here. (In other words, it helps if you post the errors.)

Comment: I don't have access to the script ATM and am going by memory.

I'll edit my post ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
message=$( command 2>&1 )
log INFO "$message"
```

Comment: I ended up doing that and switching log destination on command return value.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, that's what I ended up doing, together with an if switch to check the command return value and set the log category appropriately.

thanks,
Eddy

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a simple [multi-level logger](https://github.com/jmorenoamor/ksh-logger) for my shell scripts, you can take a look for use,  inspiration, or whatever you want.

Comment: Perfect work mate. I was looking for such easy to use and lightweight framework. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear that your problem is related to logging (it looks like your trouble is capturing the text to log, which glenn jackman has ably suggested a solution for), but just in case, you might wish to be aware of the `logger` command found on most Unix systems—it provides shell scripts the ability to write the system log.  It has various levels and priorities and everything.  Very handy.

Comment: Hi that would be a good one but I don't have access to syslog configuration.

Thanks anyhow
eddy

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `$()`, you need to use spaces and a semicolon with your curly braces (if you even need them):

```
{ command; }
```